# App script is unable to send a reminder message to telegram with a time based trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

This code should be able to send a reminder, however once execution is complete I do not receive any reminder on the telegram bot, I have made sure to input the API key, sheet ID and webappURL

```html
function reminder() {
  const returnFormattedDate = (date) =>
    Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT+8", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  dateCols = paradeStateSheet
    .getRange(1, 4, 1, 62)
    .getValues()
    .flat()
    .filter((date) => date != "")
    .map(returnFormattedDate);
  dateCol = dateCols.indexOf(correctedDate) * 2 + 4;

  peopleList = paradeStateSheet.getRange(3, 2, totalSheetUsers, 2).getValues();
  paradeStates = paradeStateSheet
    .getRange(3, dateCol, totalSheetUsers, 2)
    .getValues();
  //Logger.log("extracted");
  startTime = Date.now();
  for (i = 0; i < totalSheetUsers; i++) {
    //Logger.log(i);
    am = paradeStates[i][0];
    pm = paradeStates[i][1];
    message = "";
    if ((am == "") & (pm == "")) {
      message =
        "Please input your AM parade state, followed by your PM parade state ASAP";
    } else if (am == "") {
      message = `Please input your AM parade state ASAP. Your PM parade state is \nPM: ${pm}`;
    } else if (pm == "") {
      message = `Please input your PM parade state ASAP. Your AM parade state is \nAM: ${am}`;
    }
    elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
    // delay of 35 ms - to avoid exceeding the rate limit of 30 msg/s
    Utilities.sleep(Math.max(0, 35 - elapsedTime));
    try {
      sendMessage(peopleList[i][0], message, STATUS_KB);
      startTime = Date.now();
    } catch (e) {}
  }
}
```

Comment: No question. No code. No idea how to help you.

Comment: What debug/error information do you have? Where are `totalSheetUsers, sendMessage` defined ?